# A homomorphism $\Phi: G \to H$ where the image of $\Phi$ has an element of order n.

Tags: group-theory, proof-verification, group-homomorphism

Assume $\Phi: G \to H$ is a homomorphism and G is a finite group.  If the image of $\Phi$ has an element of order n, then G has an element of order n.

Proof: Assume $\Phi: G \to H$ is a homomorphism, and assume $\exists \Phi(g)\in Im \Phi$ such that $|\Phi(g)|=n$

$\implies \Phi(g)^n=e_{h}$ and by the homomorphism property we have $\Phi(g)^n=\Phi(g^n)=e_{h}$

Since $|G|<\infty$, it follows that $|g^n|\leq G$.

I am having trouble finishing this proof.
I had initially ended it by stating:

We know $\Phi(e_g)=e_h \therefore e_g=(g^n)$

But I realized that this conclusion is incorrect. Any help on how to proceed is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $h$ be an element of $\Phi(G)$ having order $n$, and choose $g\in G$ such that $\Phi(g)=h$. If $g$ has order $m$, then
$$ h^m=\Phi(g)^m=\Phi(g^m)=\Phi(e)=e $$
hence $n$ divides $m$, and $g^{\frac{m}{n}}$ has order $n$.

Comment: This seems like a very concise one liner versus my long attempt.  Thank you.

Comment: No problem, I'm glad it was helpful.

Comment: Quick question, why did the statement "G is a finite group" have anything to do with this proof? Does this proof fall through if G is infinite?

Comment: My proof needed the fact that $g$ has some (finite) order $m$. And the example $G=\mathbb{Z}$, $H=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ (with $\Phi$ the quotient map) shows that the claim can fail if $G$ is infinite.

Comment: Ah, alrighty, thank you for the clarification.